# Obtaining predictions from an mgcv::gam fit that contains a matrix "by" variable to a smooth

Tags: r, prediction, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I just discovered that `mgcv::s()` permits one to supply a matrix to its `by` argument, permitting one to smooth a continuous variable with separate smooths for each of a combination of variables (and their interactions if so desired). However, I'm having trouble getting sensible predictions from such models, for example:

```
library(mgcv) #for gam
library(ggplot2) #for plotting

#Generate some fake data
set.seed(1) #for replicability of this example
myData = expand.grid(
    var1 = c(-1,1)
    , var2 = c(-1,1)
    , z = -10:10
)
myData$y = rnorm(nrow(myData)) + (myData$z^2 + myData$z*4) * myData$var1 + (3*myData$z^2 + myData$z) * myData$var2 #note additive effects of var1 and var2

#plot the data
ggplot(
    data = myData
    , mapping = aes(
        x = z
        , y = y
        , colour = factor(var1)
        , linetype = factor(var2)
    )
)+
geom_line(
    alpha = .5
)

#reformat to matrices
zMat = matrix(rep(myData$z,times=2),ncol=2)
xMat = matrix(c(myData$var1,myData$var2),ncol=2)

#get the fit
fit = gam(
    formula = myData$y ~ s(zMat,by=xMat,k=5)
)

#get the predictions and plot them
predicted = myData
predicted$value = predict(fit)
ggplot(
    data = predicted
    , mapping = aes(
        x = z
        , y = value
        , colour = factor(var1)
        , linetype = factor(var2)
    )
)+
geom_line(
    alpha = .5
)
```

Yields this plot of the input data:

[image: input data plot]

And this obviously awry plot of the predicted values:

[image: output data plot]

Whereas replacing the gam fit above with:

```
fit = gam(
    formula = y ~ s(z,by=var1,k=5) + s(z,by=var2,k=5)
    , data = myData
)
```

but otherwise running the same code yields this reasonable plot of predicted values:

[image: other output plot]

What am I doing wrong here?